# I can't seem to source .env file in python VENV any solution to that

Tags: python, windows-10, python-venv, .env

I am unable to use enviornment variables in my python virtual enviornment created by running

`python -m venv .`   inside the project folder

and after that I created a `.env`  file to store my enviornment variables but can't seems to use it

contents of the `.env` file

```
export PROJECT_KEY=d07gnvfd_8Z1BZntSDXLCaEXG55mB9YVhZCnQE8vD
```

currently on windows 10

if I try to do a source to that .env file it's giving me this

`'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I also used a env.bat file for alternatives but it's not working

Comment: There is no `source` on Windows. It does not exist. `source` is something that you would typically see on Linux and Mac shells, not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

"Read the OS environment variables" and "read environment variables from .env" differ.
For reading variables from env, you should use "dotenv" package;

Activate the virtualenv and install related package;

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

now you can the add path of .env file and get variables from this file;

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env') # add path of .env file if the script and .env file are same path, use like this
print(os.getenv("SAMPLE_VARIABLE_FROM_ENV_FILE"))
```